# Track account creation in Google Analytics

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics

I want to setup an event or goal in Google Analytics to track account creation, as that is a success metric for my magento site. An event is a js append to a link that is clicked and a goal can be the js link or a destination url.

It doesn't look like there is a unique url that I can only associated with account creation. Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Background on Magento setup:

- I have social login and manual login
- I require confirmation of email address before they can login

Answer (score 1):

you could add a `_trackEvent` call to the buttons but social login might make it impossible since creating the account happens in the background.

Maybe add the event to a page after the account is created and store in the customer data you've shown it hiding it on other page views

Comment: I was thinking about trying to add the event to auto trigger when the success message pops up after they successfully login. That may be a bit hacky though.

Comment: yeah kind of sounds hacky. But this is a difficult one so might be your only solution

Comment: I'll play with it and see what I can figure out. I'll post the solution here when done.